# How to access dictionary data outside its method on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am creating a weather app with Swift. So I have retrieved the JSON data and stored it in a dictionary:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ///////getting URL:

    let mainAddress = NSURL(string: "https://...") //for NY



    //Now, getting the data syncronously by creating a session object::
    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask =
    sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(mainAddress!, completionHandler: {
        (location:NSURL!, response:NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in



        //using the if statement to avoid crashing when the URL is wrong.
        if error == nil {
            //Now, creating a dataObject for the task:
            let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
            //getting a formated dictionary of the data from URL:
            let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary //added '!' to NSdata for now

        }




    })

    downloadTask.resume()
```

I have used a Struct, in a difirent file, in order to organize and initialize the dictionary's data:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WatchKit
//created the struct just to better organize the data. In the future, if the API keys change, it would be easier to ajust the code, rather than if the data was directly read from the API onto the graph.

struct hourlyData {


///declaring only keys that have Integers as value.
var daylyPop0 : Int
var daylyPop1 : Int
var daylyPop2 : Int
var daylyPop3 : Int
var daylyPop4 : Int



var summaryNowDay : String
var summaryNowNight : String
var iconNow : String
var currentTime: String?

//Initializing the values here. With optional properties:
init(weatherDictionary:NSDictionary){

    daylyPop0 = weatherDictionary["daily0_pop"] as Int
    daylyPop1 = weatherDictionary["daily1_pop"] as Int
    daylyPop2 = weatherDictionary["daily4_pop"] as Int
    daylyPop3 = weatherDictionary["daily3_pop"] as Int
    daylyPop4 = weatherDictionary["daily2_pop"] as Int

}
```

Now, I am implementing a chart for it. So I need to access the values from the dictionary in order to implement them on the chart. However, I've been unsuccessfull after many attemps. 
The code lets me access the hourlyData struct, but not the weatherDictionary, since it was declared inside the session declaration.

Anyone knows an effective way to do it?

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you ever called the init method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for asynchronous request:

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var dict = NSDictionary()

var yourSavedData = hourlyData()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in

    if data == nil
    {
        println("Error in connection")
        return
    }

    var error = NSErrorPointer()
    dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as NSDictionary

    if error != nil
    {
        println(error.debugDescription)
        return
    }

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in


            if let yourDict = dict as? NSDictionary
            {
                yourSavedData = hourlyData(yourDict!)
            }

        }

    })
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dejan. But when I try to run it, theres a error message saying: "Type 'NSURL' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'". Any idea of what that means?

Comment: it seems that the previous issue was solved. But now, in the 'if let' statement, there is an error saying: Conditional downcast from NSDictionary to NSDictionary always succeeds.

Comment: Sry, still having the 'StringLiteralConvertible' error for the URL.

Comment: It seems like youre trying to convert a String to Int. How does your JSON look like ?

Comment: Yes, I was previously trying to do that. Because the JSON had the data all in Strings. Now, it is like this:

Comment: "hourly0_temp": 23,
    "hourly0_pop": 0,
    "hourly1_time": 1423731600,
    "hourly1_temp": 22,
    "hourly1_pop": 0,
    "hourly2_time": 1423735200,
    "hourly2_temp": 20,
    "hourly2_pop": 0,
    "hourly3_time": 1423738800,
    "hourly3_temp": 19,
    "hourly3_pop": 0,
    "hourly4_time": 1423742400,
    "hourly4_temp": 18,
    "hourly4_pop": 0,
................................

Comment: how did you declare url?

like this? :

var url = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")

Comment: and where do you get the error ? which line? paste that line

Comment: var request = NSURLRequest(URL: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/......../37.8267,-122.423")

Comment: The URL bit is fixed now, I was missing some code. Now, I still keep on getting: 'Conditional downcast from NSDictionary to NSDictionary always succeeds', under the if let statement.

Comment: I am also getting: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value', under the 'daylyPop0 = weatherDictionary["daily0_pop"] as Int'

Comment: make sure you have the "daily0_pop" key in the json

Comment: I have. I also have added an answer over here with more code details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  **if let** to parse dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after the answers you guys posted I've updated the code a little. This is how the viewDidLoad looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ///////getting URL:

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://..........") //for NY
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var dict = NSDictionary()

    var yourSavedData = hourlyData(weatherDictionary: NSDictionary())

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in

        if data == nil
        {
            println("Error in connection")
            return
        }

        var error = NSErrorPointer()
        dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as! NSDictionary

        if error != nil
        {
            println(error.debugDescription)
            return
        }

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in


            if let yourDict = dict as? NSDictionary
            {
                yourSavedData = hourlyData(weatherDictionary: yourDict)
            }

        }

    })
```

And this is how the other swift file with the Struct looks like:

```
struct hourlyData {


///declaring only keys that have Integers as value.
var daylyPop0 : Int
var daylyPop1 : Int
var daylyPop2 : Int
var daylyPop3 : Int
var daylyPop4 : Int



var summaryNowDay : String
var summaryNowNight : String
var iconNow : String
var currentTime: String?

//Initializing the values here. With optional properties:
init(weatherDictionary:NSDictionary){

    daylyPop0 = weatherDictionary["hourly10_pop"] as! Int
    daylyPop1 = weatherDictionary["hourly11_pop"] as! Int
    daylyPop2 = weatherDictionary["hourly12_pop"] as! Int
    daylyPop3 = weatherDictionary["hourly13_pop"] as! Int
    daylyPop4 = weatherDictionary["hourly14_pop"] as! Int



    summaryNowDay = weatherDictionary["today_day_fcttext_metric"] as! String
    summaryNowNight = weatherDictionary["today_night_fcttext_metric"] as! String

    iconNow = weatherDictionary["current_icon"] as! String

    let currentTimeIntValue = weatherDictionary["forecast_time"] as! Int
    currentTime = dateStringFromUnixTime(currentTimeIntValue)


}

//Converting unixTime to a desired style:::used ShortStyle in this case:
func dateStringFromUnixTime(unixTime: Int) -> String{

    let timeInSeconds = NSTimeInterval(unixTime)

    let weatherDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInSeconds)

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(weatherDate)

}
```

}

Now the code looks fine, and it does not show any error, besides a warning under the 'if let', which says: Conditional cast from 'NSDictionary' to 'NSDictionary' always succeeds. 
When I run the simulator, it crashes and displays: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Highlighting, in green, the code line: daylyPop0 = weatherDictionary["hourly10_pop"] as! Int

Comment: Ofcourse, you are sending an empty dictionary to the constructor, thats why you get the unexpected nil. Use this instead var yourSavedData = hourlyData()

Comment: whenever I try to use 'hourlyData()'; there is an error message saying: missing argument for parameter 'weatherDictionary' in call.

Comment: Then add another init, with no arguments, and dont assign anything, just add init() {}, probally you'll still have to assign the values though, so assign them as empty strings = "" or 0 if int, if needed

Comment: Thanks a lot Dejan, solved the issue. You had a lot of patience here.

Comment: Sry mate, I dont have enough points for that...new to stackOverFlow/